# Some confusion regarding packets

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, packet, mtu

After some while of googling I'm really confused. The answer is right in front of my eyes, but I still don't get it! It is said that:

> The maximum packet size is 65535(including packet headers) ,but it actually isn't! It is the Maximum Transmission Unit(MTU) value!

From a programmer point-of-view, what is the value that I should take into consideration? If that value that I should consider is the MTU, what is the minimum MTU value that ever exists in this world?

One more thing. Since UDP uses datagrams to send packets over the network, having a maximum packet size makes sense. However, TCP transmits data as a stream of octets, so why is there a maximum packet size? (Just curious) **Explained in comments below ✓**

Comment: MTU is an IP thing, not a TCP thing.

Comment: Doesn't TCP send the bytes 1 by 1(not a whole packet)?

Comment: TCP uses packets under the hood to provide a "stream of bytes" to applications. Also, we have no way to know what whoever said that might have meant by it without any context. The MTU and maximum packet size are the same.

Comment: TCP uses IP, which is packet-based.

Comment: Ok now I get that, Thanks.

Comment: Also, who said the maximum packet size is 65,535? There is no common platform where either the maximum packet size or the MTU is 65,535 or anything close to it.

Comment: Google "Maximum TCP packet size" @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @None I'm not sure what you expect me to get from  that. I get a whole bunch of articles that explain all sorts of things, but I don't see anything that says what you're saying.

Comment: First Result: The absolute limitation on TCP packet size is 64K (65535 bytes), but in practicality this is far larger than the size of any packet you will see, because the lower layers (e.g. ethernet) have lower packet sizes. The MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) for Ethernet, for instance, is 1500 bytes.

Comment: Is the minimum packet size the MTU, 65535 or the one that is smallest?

Comment: I think we're confusing TCP theory with TCP practice. Are you asking a theoretical question about TCP or a practical question about TCP on the Internet?

Comment: Practical, the real thing, the size that I can't go beyond, or whatever you call this.

Comment: @None What do you mean by "the size I can't go beyond"? You don't deal with TCP packets unless you're writing a TCP implementation. TCP doesn't provide any kind of packet interface to applications.

Comment: I mean when I call a Socket.Send(byte[] bytes); method (c#), could the passed in byte array be of any size?

Comment: @None Yes. And then it's the TCP implementation's job to figure out what packets to send to get those bytes to the other side. That's what TCP does.

Comment: Same for UDP datagrams?

Comment: @None No. UDP is totally different since UDP provides a datagram API, not a byte stream API. Datagram APIs preserve message boundaries and have message size limitations. (Also, UDP's performance can drop drastically as datagram size goes up.)

Comment: So what is the maximum number of bytes that I can send over the network in one datagram @DavidSchwartz? MTU or 65,535?

Comment: @None 65,535. But note that packet loss will be multiplied since the loss of any packet causes the entire datagram to be lost.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much. I hope I could vote up several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From a programmer point-of-view, what is the value that I should take into consideration? If that value that I should consider is the MTU, what is the  minimum MTU value that ever exists in this world?

From a programmer point-of-view, you don't care what's going on under the hood. Just use TCP as a stream of bytes since that's what TCP provides to the application programmer. Do try not to make lots of small writes though, as that can cause inefficient network utilization and extra latency.

Comment: So can I just send and number of bytes I want??

Comment: Yes. Ideally, send as many as you have. Try not to dribble small bits because that will cause the TCP implementation to behave badly. If you can send at least 2KB on each go, you'll be fine. Obviously, if you have less data to send, send less.

Comment: So may I just send a 100 KB in one packet and no one can do anything?

Comment: @None Why do you bring packets into this? We're talking about TCP's byte stream API which has nothing to do with packets. Are you writing a TCP implementation? If not, you don't ever touch a packet, that's between the TCP implementation and the network.

Comment: I mean calling the Socket.Send(byte[] bytes) function passing in a byte array of length 100,000. May I do this?

Comment: @None Yes, since TCP provides a byte stream API to you, you may send a stream of bytes. There are no packets here, this is a byte stream API.

Comment: Same for UDP "packets"?

Comment: See comment on question. No. UDP provides a datagram API to applications which is nothing like a byte stream API. A UDP datagram may be split over several packets.